# trying to run npm start but getting a port error message

Tags: npm-start

when i'm trying to run "npm start" i'm getting this error message Port "1234" could not be used
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJYuc.png)

see my packege.json

```
{
  "name": "simplefolio",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": "true",
  "description": "A clean, beautiful and responsive portfolio template for Developers!",
  "source": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/cobidev/simplefolio"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Jacobo Martinez",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/cobidev/simplefolio/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/cobidev/simplefolio#readme",
  
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "parcel": "^2.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "vanilla-tilt": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: when i do npm-start i'm getting the below
mekstein@FPS104 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/simplefolio (master)
$ npm-start
bash: npm-start: command not found

mekstein@FPS104 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/simplefolio (master)
$

Answer (score 0):

Do you have VLC running on your computer? It might be using that port: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Can you try to use a different port?

Comment: how would  i use a different port for nmp start?

Comment: Good morning!
still getting    Port "1234" could not be used
Server running at http://localhost:56486
Building...
Bundling...
Packaging & Optimizing...
√ Built in 695ms

after unistalling VLC

Comment: is there a way to change the port to something else?